# What is the meaning of "-h" option in using gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, redis, solaris

I am building the redis C client on Solaris 10, and the final step of generating dynamic library is like this:

```
cc -G -o libhiredis.so -h libhiredis.so.0.11  net.o hiredis.o sds.o async.o
```

The `cc` refers to `gcc`:

```
bash-3.00# which cc
/usr/local/bin/cc
bash-3.00# ls -lt /usr/local/bin/cc
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           3 Mar 24  2011 /usr/local/bin/cc -> gcc
bash-3.00# /usr/local/bin/gcc -v
Reading specs from /data/local/bin/../lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/3.4.6/specs  
Configured with: ../configure --with-as=/usr/ccs/bin/as --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld --          enable-shared --enable-languages=c,c++,f77
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.6
```

From the https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Index.html, I know the "-G" option is "Create a shared object". But what does the "-h" mean? I can't find it in the https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Index.html.

Comment: Is that a linker option instead? `man ld` seems to give consistent information given your example.

Comment: Passing parameters from `gcc` into `ld` is usually done by `-Wl,OPTION`. I don't suppose `ld` options are directly available in `gcc` so why would `-h` be more special?

Comment: @dragosht: Personally, I think maybe the cause is generating a shared library. Just a presumption.

Comment: @NanXiao It seems you have figured out what `-h` does just fine. Now the question is how that a `gcc` linker option got no documentation?

Comment: @dragosht: I have find "-h" in `ld` manual on Solaris, and I have checked the hiredis Makefile once again, and find it has customization for Solaris: `DYLIB_MAKE_CMD=$(CC) -G -o $(DYLIBNAME) -h $(DYLIB_MINOR_NAME) $(LDFLAGS)`. So I think maybe it just works OK on Solaris.

Comment: @NanXiao Agreed. However, you're using `gcc -h ...`, not `ld -h`. All I'm saying is the argument should probably also be mentioned in the `gcc` man/info pages (no idea why it is currently not in there).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a linker option (just checked with 'man ld'):

```
  -h name 
  -soname=name
           When creating an ELF shared object, set the internal DT_SONAME
           field to the specified name.  When an executable is linked with a
           shared object which has a DT_SONAME field, then when the executable
           is run the dynamic linker will attempt to load the shared object
           specified by the DT_SONAME field rather than the using the file
           name given to the linker.
```